# task cat throwing "no suitible partition" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, aws-cloudformation

When trying to run taskcat locally, I am getting:

```
[WARN   ] : No stacks were created... skipping cleanup.
[ERROR  ] : ValueError cannot find suitable AWS partition
```

from the console.  I am using version 0.9.25.  The master template yaml is my cloud formation template.  My .taskcat.yml is below.

```
project:
  name:  automation
  parameters:
    "ParameterKey": "VPCId"
    "ParameterValue": "123"

  regions:
    ["us-east-2", "us-east-1"]

  template: ./ci/templates/master.template.yaml
tests:
  my-test:
      template: ./ci/templates/master.template.yaml
```

I am not sure where the error is occurring, am I missing something in my .taskcat.yml?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was a **permissions issue**.
I wrote a taskcat part of the CI that runs on multiple accounts simultaneously, within the codebuild platform. I got this error when the profiles were not set up correctly. I Added here a template on how to do that in the correct way.

My .taskcat.yml:

```
general:
  auth:
    default: default
    {region}: { profile name of account a }

project:
  name: ...
  regions:
    ....
  s3_bucket : ...
 
tests:
  name of test one:
    template: ...
    regions:
      ...
```

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region=...
output=json
[profile { profile name of account a }]
region=...
output=json
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=...
aws_secret_access_key=...
aws_session_token=...
[{ profile name of account a }]
aws_access_key_id=...
aws_secret_access_key=...
aws_session_token=...
```